# htmlspecialchars(): Invalid multibyte sequence in argument CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem with a codeigniter's functions. 
This is my controller code:
http://pastebin.com/YGj9ExkU

On my local machine it works perfect, but on my remote server it returns to me warning:

Severity: Warning
Message: htmlspecialchars(): Invalid multibyte sequence in argument
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 553

The PHP versions is same - 5.3

I think that problem inside my _clean function, but i don't sure about. My searching results don't have success. Some people said that problem with encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify the encoding to **UTF-8**, e.g.

```
htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

The default for `htmlspecialchars()` is ISO-8859-1, which might explain why you get that error.